# How to manually remove LaTeX packages in Ubuntu (installed from Debian Repositories)

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu

My laptop (OS: Ubuntu xenial) has a very small disk space (16 GB) so I installed one of the `texlive` packages (via Debian Repositories using `apt`). I needed certain features that forced me to download `texlive-fonts-extra`, but I don't really need *all* that comes with that package. In particular, I'd like to erase a package called 'Countries of Europe' (since I don't live in Europe, I see no use for it).

I'd like to delete several other fonts (LaTeX packages) too, and all I've found so far in Ubuntu and TeXLive is using `tlmgr`; which doesn't work with Debian Repositories.

As a side note, I've seen many posts regarding TeX packages installation (manually or otherwise) but very few regarding uninstalling. I think this question could be useful to other users.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'd suggest removing ubuntu/Debian texlive completely. Instead manually install upstream texlive (see tug.org/texlive), in the installer choose a minimal/small scheme and then use `tlmgr` (the proper unlimited version) to add the packages/fonts you actually need

Comment: the linux packaged ones only really work at the level of the apt collections although nothing that bad would happen if you simply deleted the files you don't want you can always do a forced apt re-install to get things back in sync if needed

Comment: I found those files and I was hesitating wether or not delete them (maybe that could trigger some 'corrupt install' error or something). But I now think I'll just delete them.

Comment: I really advise, if you need new (or even not so old) TeXLive characteristics, to do a local "portable" installation of TeXLive --- it's what I do. I do not remove the standard packages to avoid dependencies nightmares, though... it's just around 5G wasted. Could be worse.